# Ошибка: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Доброе утро, я туплю, не могу понять, что не правильно, то есть я знаю, в какой строке, но что именно и как исправить- не понятно, вот упрощенный донельзя вариант того, что мне нужно.

```
class Tree{
public:
    void add_element(Tree);
    vector<Tree> get_vector();
};

class Directory: public Tree{
private:
    string name;
    vector<Tree> element;
public:
    Directory(string name){
        this->name = name;
    }
    void add_element(Tree tree){
        element.push_back(tree);
    }
};

int main(){
    Tree *root = new Directory("root");
    Tree *d1 = new Directory("klk");

    root->add_element(*d1);// тут он дает ошибку, добавлю в конце кода

}
//error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Tree::add_element(class Tree)" (?add_element@Tree@@QAEXV1@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Пробовал оборачивать в shared_ptr, ..., подскажите, где туплю, спасибо. Может я что-то не правильно делаю инициализацией вектора?..., спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот минимально переделанный вариант, который компилируется

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Tree{
public:
    // здесь должно быть virtual, потому что здесь абстрактный виртуальный метод
    // если этого не будет, компилятор не сможет выбрать правильную реализацию
    // и будет ругаться, что не может найти реализацию метода (это как в Вашей 
    // ошибке - компилятор пытался найти реализацию виртуального метода)
    virtual void add_element(Tree* tree) = 0;
    virtual vector<Tree*> get_vector() = 0;
};

class Directory: public Tree{
private:
    string name;
    vector<Tree*> element;
public:
    Directory(string name){
        this->name = name;
    }
    void add_element(Tree* tree){
        element.push_back(tree);
    }
    vector<Tree*> get_vector() {
       return element;
    }
};

int main(){
    Tree *root = new Directory("root");
    Tree *d1 = new Directory("klk");

    root->add_element(d1);

}
```

Comment: я попробовал, получаю ругань на передачу объекта в функцию, по видимому туда можно передать только указатель

Comment: Видимо у Вас пример "побольше":) Мой вариант компилируется?

Comment: нет убрал все лишнее оставил только эту функцию и ее тело очистил

Comment: ваш компилируется буду разбираться

Comment: я согласен по поводу virtual, но почему если сделать ф-ию не абсолютно виртуальной, он начинает ругаться?

Comment: Если функция не "абсолютно виртуальная", то у нее должна быть реализация. У Вас ее нет, поэтому линковщик (не компилятор) и ругается - он не может найти ее.

Comment: ой, ну вот, я так и знал, что где-то туплю, спс, разобрался.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте изменить компоновщик, поставить /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE вместо /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.

Установка данного параметра компоновщика в среде разработки Visual Studio
1. Откройте диалоговое окно Страницы свойств проекта.
2. Выберите папку Компоновщик.
3. Выберите страницу свойств Система.
4. В SubSystem поставить /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE вместо /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/799kze2z.aspx